# Eclipse project been ignored when trying to commit to Git Repository

Tags: eclipse, egit

I am using eclipse and EGit plugin.
I pressed by mistake Team -> Ignore for my whole project in eclipse and now is not recognising my changes and I can't commit.
How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can undo that through the UI, so try searching for a `.gitignore` file in your `workspace` or `local repository`.
References to your project files should be in it, edit the file, remove references and save it.